# Netlogo: Is it possible to change the size and font of the label attached to a turtle?

Tags: netlogo

I only know the color of the turtle label can be changed. How about the size, position and font(such as if i wanna **BOLD** it). Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about position and font. But you can change the size with right-click on the world (where the turtles live) and change the font size there.
Here are some pages that deal with label changes: [change label color](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/label-color.html) and [another](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/plabel.html) that deals with labels of patches and a [model](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/LabelPositionExample) in which the position of the labels is changed.

Comment: Thank you Hannah!

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @dariox, apparently the page does not exist anymore. I added some other links that deal with changes of the label